# Android Facebook integration getting e-mail id

Tags: android, facebook, email

In my android app i have done Facebook integration.Facebook login works fine.How can i get user's email id from Facebook integration in android?
please help.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use permission and this code

```
     loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList( "email","user_birthday"));
```

and use Graph Api

```
  private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallBack = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {



           progressDialog.dismiss();
            // App code
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {

                            Log.e("response: ", response + "");
                            Log.e("object: ", object + "");
                                try {
                                    userfbData = new UserfbData();
                                    userfbData.facebookID = object.getString("id").toString();
                                    userfbData.email = object.getString("email").toString();
                                    userfbData.name = object.getString("name").toString();
                                    userfbData.gender = object.getString("gender").toString();
                                     userfbData.birthday=object.getString("birthday").toString();
                                    PrefUtils.setCurrentUser(userfbData,LoginActivity.this);
                                    Log.d("flist","flist"+ userfbData.flist);

                                }catch (Exception e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            //  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"welcome "+userfbData.name+userfbData.email+userfbData.gender+userfbData.birthday, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"welcome "+ userfbData.name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,LogoutActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();

                        }

                    });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
           progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("error","error"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
```

UserFbData

```
public class UserfbData {


    public String name;

    public String email;

    public String facebookID;

    public String gender;

    public  String birthday;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a GraphRequest call to get personal information of the logged in user such as id, name, email etc.

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken,
    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
            try {
                String email = object.getString("email");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            }
        }
    }
);
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields","email");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```